# Ionic2 resize Modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, ionic2

I'm trying to resize a modal, to make it look like an alert, because I need a custom alert, so the easiest way its to create a modal.

The thing is, I don't know how to make the modal small, so it doesn't use the whole screen.

I have this CSS:

```
    .modal-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 65%; 
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
  }
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar class="modal-wrapper">
    <ion-title>alertModal</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I dont think you need to set ion-navbar class as modal-wrapper..that class is generated by the ion-modal

Comment: I think that i solved the problem. I had to put the modal-wrapper class inside ion-model, and that solved the problem.